# Tag synonym request: [keyword] -> [keywords]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, retag-request

[keyword](/questions/tagged/keyword) 206 questions. Wiki excerpt.
[keywords](/questions/tagged/keywords) 373 questions. No wiki.

I suggest that [keyword](/questions/tagged/keyword) be made synonym of [keywords](/questions/tagged/keywords), and the wiki excerpt be copied.

---

**EDIT**
As suggested by *Anna Lear*, I inverted the request from [keywords](/questions/tagged/keywords) -> [keyword](/questions/tagged/keyword) to [keyword](/questions/tagged/keyword) -> [keywords](/questions/tagged/keywords)

Comment: Status completed. [Keywords] is now a synonym of [Keyword].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually we go the other way around: singular -> plural, tag with fewer questions -> tag with more questions. So I'd go [keyword](/questions/tagged/keyword) -> [keywords](/questions/tagged/keywords) instead.

The tag wiki can be copied over if needed. I'm not sure if that's automatically handled when two tags are synonymized and/or merged.

Comment: I see. Your solution may be best then.