# Retag-request: [widget] 's [task] 's [condition] 's

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

Plural 's' tag names seems to be the so-convention. I therefore suggest we change these tags:

`[widget] ⇒ [widgets]` Renaming [widget](/questions/tagged/widget) (2,077 questions) to [widgets](/questions/tagged/widgets) (527 q's) and making [widget](/questions/tagged/widget) a synonym.
 `[task] ⇒ [tasks]` Renaming [task](/questions/tagged/task) (720 q's) to [tasks](/questions/tagged/tasks) (235 q's) and making [task](/questions/tagged/task) a synonym.
 `[condition] ⇒ [conditions]` Renaming [condition](/questions/tagged/condition) (457 q's) to [conditions](/questions/tagged/conditions) (186 q's) and making [condition](/questions/tagged/condition) a synonym. Updating as I find more things in need of attention.
 `[keyword] ⇒ [keywords]` Renaming [keyword](/questions/tagged/keyword) (283 q's) to [keywords](/questions/tagged/keywords) (449 q's). [Also requested here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111559/tag-synonym-request-keyword-keywords).
 `[tag: webkit.net]` (27 q`s). Burn it. They should properly be tagged [webkit](/questions/tagged/webkit) (3171 q's).

Comment: `Plural 's' tag names seems to be the so-convention` -- Even though, in all three of your examples, SOPedians make more use of the singular tag than the plural one.

Comment: @Robert Harvey. My point beeing. **There are 2 tags for the same thing**. Since I see that (80-90% ? round numbers) of other tags make use of plural tags exclusively. Singular terms is (mostly) for well established concepts. So `[redirect] [url] [preview]`. Also for concept which commonly appear in singular `[photo-gallery] [conflict]`  **With looser concepts**, it is definately more common, _the exact **why** is perhaps a bit vague, another question_, **using plural names** `[books] [properties] [web-services]`. Then again there are cases when I can see 2 cases justified `[word] [words]`.

Comment: The right thing to do would to establish a _canon page_ (my first language is not english) `stackoverflow terms` _to distinguish which tags should be plural and which should be singular_. (Until then we are living in an undefined limbo).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merge singular and plural tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6752/merge-singular-and-plural-tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completed:

[widgets](/questions/tagged/widgets) ==> [widget](/questions/tagged/widget) 
[tasks](/questions/tagged/tasks) ==> [task](/questions/tagged/task) 
[conditions](/questions/tagged/conditions) ==> [condition](/questions/tagged/condition) 
[keywords](/questions/tagged/keywords) ==> [keyword](/questions/tagged/keyword)